# Specific number of test/train size for each class in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, split, scikit-learn, classification

**Data:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'classes':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'b':[3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'c':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16]})
```

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X = np.array(data[['b','c']])  
y = np.array(data['classes'])     
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=4)
```

**Question:**

train_test_split will randomly choose test set from all the classes. Is there any way to have **the same** number of test set for **each class**? (For example, two data from class 1 and two data from class 2. Note that the total number of each classes are not equal)

**Expected result:**

```
y_test
array([1, 2, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: There can be an arbitrary number of classes and `test_size` is always equal  to it?

Comment: I am not sure, I got your point completely. But, The result of test_size can be **not covered** by all the classes.

Comment: Is number of unique `classes` from `data` always equal to `test_size` (2 in your example)?

Comment: No, this is a fake data. My actual data has 5 classes. I am looking for a general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually no sklearn function or parameter to do this directly. 
 The `stratify` samples *proportionately*, which is not what you want as you indicated in your comment.

You can build a custom function, which is relatively slower but not tremendously slow on an absolute basis.  Note that this is built for pandas objects.

```
def train_test_eq_split(X, y, n_per_class, random_state=None):
    if random_state:
        np.random.seed(random_state)
    sampled = X.groupby(y, sort=False).apply(
        lambda frame: frame.sample(n_per_class))
    mask = sampled.index.get_level_values(1)

    X_train = X.drop(mask)
    X_test = X.loc[mask]
    y_train = y.drop(mask)
    y_test = y.loc[mask]

    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

Example case:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'classes': np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]),
                     'b': np.random.randn(60),
                     'c': np.random.randn(60)})
y = data.pop('classes')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_eq_split(
    data, y, n_per_class=5, random_state=123)

y_test.value_counts()
# 3    5
# 2    5
# 1    5
# Name: classes, dtype: int64
```

How it works:

1. Perform a groupby on `X` and sample *n* values from each group.
2. Get the inner index of this object.  This is the index for our test sets, and its set difference with the original data is our train index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I believe your answer is right if the frequency of the classes are the same. What if you have 10 from class 1, 20 from class 2 and 30 from class 3. Now, how can I have 5 test set from each class?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry.  Let me think about it.  So in this case, your train set would just be the remaining 45 samples?

Comment: One other question: say you have test_size of 16 and 5 classes.  How should those be split because 16 is not divisible by 5?

Comment: Yes, the remaining 45 is your train set. For your second question, actually we define the test_size number (say n number from each class). In this case you will not face that issue.

Comment: This raises `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'groupby'`

Comment: @usernumber You somehow managed to pass a numpy-array instead of a pandas-dataframe.