# numpy groupby function raises an attribute error

Tags: python, numpy

When I run the following code

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(10)
A.groupby
```

I get the error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'groupby'`.

I uninstalled numpy, by running `pip3 uninstall numpy` multiple times, until it said `WARNING: Skipping numpy as it is not installed.`. I upgraded pip, and I reinstalled numpy.

How do I fix this error?

I am using pip 19.3.1 and numpy 1.17.4.

Comment: May be this will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: How come you think `groupby` is a method of numpy arrays?  Maybe you look for `pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10)).groupby()`?

Comment: @PrinceFrancis Not really. The answer to that question is the function I'm trying to use and that raises an error.

Comment: @Alfe I was trying to use the code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602194/3128109 where `groupby` is used as an `numpy.ndarray` method

Comment: That's using a dataframe. Numpy doesn't have a `groupby` so the only fix is to not try and use a method that doesn't exist

Comment: In your comment in the question you linked to you made the error of passing a numpy-array instead of a pandas-dataframe.  Stick to the provided code (`data = pd.DataFrame({ ...})` and `train_test_eq_split(data, ...)`), and it should work.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got tells you exactly what the problem is: numpy arrays do not have the attribute`groupby`. I figure you wanted to use the method `groupby()`, but numpy doesn't have that either. What you want to do is use a pandas dataframe and then group by a specific column, like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'], 'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
df.groupby(['Animal'])
```

Example taken from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)